# dplyr calculate a new column by applying summarise function on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column (`CNT`) in a dataframe called `df`. The value will be calculated using `summarise` function from `dplyr` package. It should return a number since I need to count a column in another dataframe (=`cars`), however the conditions for filtration is determined by the values in 2 columns of `df`.

**dataframe:**

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("my_speed" = 11:20, "my_dist" = c(17,20,15,17,21,23,28,36,50,80))
```

As an example, this is the calculation for the first row of `df`.

```
x=df[1,1]
y=df[1,2]

cars %>% 
group_by(speed) %>% 
filter(speed==x & dist==y) %>% 
summarise(count=n()) %>% 
select (count)
```

I am trying to figure out how I can use `summarise()` or another method to do this easily. NOTE that if `summarise()` returns no records, we should show zero.

```
df %>% 
rowwise() %>%
filter(speed==my_spped & dist==my_dist) %>% 
summarise(count=n()) %>% 
select (count) %>% 
mutate(CNT=count)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `rowwise`, we can get the `sum` of the logical expression directly instead of doing additional operations

```
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(CNT = sum((cars$speed == my_speed) & (cars$dist == my_dist)))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   my_speed my_dist   CNT
#      <int>   <dbl> <int>
# 1       11      17     1
# 2       12      20     1
# 3       13      15     0
# 4       14      17     0
# 5       15      21     0
# 6       16      23     0
# 7       17      28     0
# 8       18      36     0
# 9       19      50     0
#10       20      80     0
```

Comment: **Performance Note:** using `Date` instead of `POSIXct` was faster, 167 seconds vs 256 seconds for my real data

Answer (score 3):

We can define a function

```
library(tidyverse)

get_count <- function(x, y) {
   cars %>% 
    summarise(count = sum(speed == x & dist == y)) %>% 
    pull(count)
}
```

and apply it for every row using `map2`

```
df %>%
  mutate(CNT = map2(my_speed, my_dist, get_count))


#   my_speed my_dist   CNT
#1        11      17     1
#2        12      20     1
#3        13      15     0
#4        14      17     0
#5        15      21     0
#6        16      23     0
#7        17      28     0
#8        18      36     0
#9        19      50     0
#10       20      80     0
```

---

The base R equivalent of the same using `apply` would be

```
get_count <- function(x) {
  nrow(subset(cars, speed == x[1] & dist == x[2]))
}

df$CNT <- apply(df, 1, get_count)
```

Comment: I had solved my problem with a similar approach, but comparing this method and using rowwise and sum function was faster. This took 474 seconds whereas rowwise and sum took 256 seconds. I guess if I could figure out how the right join solution worked it would have been faster

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

```
library(dplyr)

cars %>%
  count(speed, dist) %>%                   # count unique (speed, dist) pairs
  right_join(dat) %>%                      # join to dat, drop all not in dat
  mutate(CNT = coalesce(n, 0L), n = NULL)  # replace NA, create CNT, drop n
```

#### Data

```
dat <- data.frame(
  speed = 11:20,
  dist = c(17, 20, 15, 17, 21, 23, 28, 36, 50, 80)
  )
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   speed  dist   CNT
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1    11    17     1
 2    12    20     1
 3    13    15     0
 4    14    17     0
 5    15    21     0
 6    16    23     0
 7    17    28     0
 8    18    36     0
 9    19    50     0
10    20    80     0
```

Comment: This method looks interesting, but I could not apply to my real problem. Basically, df that I have defined here is a range of dates and names. dataset `cars` in my real problem is a column of `name` and 3 columns of dates. I need to run an aggregate function using the names and the date from df. I have to apply many `WHERE` clause to my aggregate function. The solution with `rowwise()` worked,  but it takes 5 minutes, I was wondering this method would be faster?

Comment: This is the code that works fine with `rowwise()`, how would you convert this to join method? `df <- df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(NRTS=sum((df2$Entry_Date<=DayOf+24*60*60-1) &
                    (df2$AssignedTo==Name) & 
                    ((df2$RTS_Date>DayOf+24*60*60-1)|is.na(df2$RTS_Date)) &
                    is.na(df2$Completion_Date)))`

Comment: @Ibo if you could provide the representative example of your data (just a small subset), and if it can wait for tomorrow, I will try to solve the problem.

Comment: I will try to create a subset, it can be a bit long, but I don't know if I can post it here not ruining the question's format. Is there anywhere we can upload it or something and not use a script to generate data? it can wait, for now I can use rowwise

Comment: Google Drive, Dropbox, or anything else would work. It is not necessary to post real data, as well.

Comment: I created a subset of two dataframes in the form of txt (space delimited) and loaded them here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hdn5zybh8wc328/data.zip?dl=0

Comment: How many rows do you have in original df2? I am interested in it because of timing. 5 min is a huge number.

Comment: df1 is like 130-200k and df2 should be around 20-30k. I can give you an accurate number on Monday

Comment: Ok, I've tried different approaches, particularly `dplyr` with `*_join`, joins with `data.table` and the approach proposed by @akrun. Solution proposed by @akrun is the fastest one (~200k randomly shuffled `df2` and original `df1`). My `*_join` and `data.table` approaches took approx. 14 seconds to do the job  on my machine, @akrun's approach is two-times faster. Which wasn't a big surprise for me, because with each post I read, @akrun climbs 10 stairs up in the list of my personal heroes :D  Adding this one, and `NA^x` trick, I think it makes 25.

Comment: the conditions I have to apply on df2 are min 3 or 4. I was wondering maybe a join could be faster, but I could not test it because I could not come up with the proper join code. if I had it, I could try it and share the exact duration. I am surprised it took only a few seconds, it was minutes on my work computer, so this will be interesting to know. After that, I will choose the right answer, which is the most efficient one in fact since all of the answers were right

Comment: I am assuming you are not going to update your answer with the code that would work with my real problem and data that I provided, so I will go ahead and mark the right answer

Comment: @Ibo Sorry, tough time at work :) There is a workaround I've tried, nothing new thought https://www.dropbox.com/s/rf3yxswb6526ep5/54473475.R?raw=1 I don't know how to apply idea of joins in your particular case, so all of that is a dance around subsetting by logical expression. My idea was to through out data not present in `df2` to reduce the amount of comparisons by `dplyr` or `data.table` joins. But it doesn't work because it seems all the names from `df1` are present in `df2`. Maybe you can develop something useful working with thous ideas.